# Why does frequency polygon have to start from and end at zero?

Tags: statistics

I have been searching a lot of materials about this but I still see no reason why we have to make a frequency polygon staring from and ending at zero while there is no such requirement for broken line graph. Who made this rule and all textbooks follow this rule?

Comment: I've never heard of a frequency polygon before (...and googling left lots of ambiguity), but I think the answer is probably because, if you had instead drawn a histogram, then outside of the bounds of the data, the frequency is $0$ (i.e. "this range of quantities never occurred").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you draw a single line segment in a frequency polygon, the area under that line segment is the same as the number of counts in the bin it spans.  For *all* the bins left of the left-most bin that has any events in it, there are zero counts in those bins, so the line segment for those bins has height $0$ and similary for bins right of the right-most bin that has any events in it.

Frequency polygons are connected, meaning the left edge of the line segment for the left-most nonempty bin must be zero and the right edge must be at height twice the number of counts in the bin (because the average height of this line segment must be the number of counts in this bin and we know how to find the area of the triangle under a line segment).  Similarly, the right end of the line segment for the right-most nonempty bin must be at height zero.

If, for a broken line graph, you were *also* to account for empty bins beyond the left- and right-most nonempty bins, you would also take the height of the line down to zero.  Usually, though, in order to not waste space with noninformative bins, you do not extend a broken line graph past the left- or right-most nonempty bin.

So the fundamental difference when both are plotted to show only the range of nonempty bins is that the left-most and right-most line segments in a frequenty polygon must descend to meet the zero-height lines extending infinitely to the left and right, past the edges of the shown portion of the graph.  For the broken line graph, you do not descend to zero until you reach the middles of the bins just outside the shown range of bins.